# Bluetooth Icon disappeared

Tags: 11.10, indicator, bluetooth

After installing Cairo-dock, the bluetooth indicator disappeared when I restarted my laptop. Bluetooth is working fine. But the bluetooth-indicator at top left of the panel is not showing up anymore. I have to go to System Settings>Bluetooth to add/remove bluetooth devices. How to bring back the bluetooth indicator?

- `/etc/xdg/autostart/bluetooth-applet.desktop` and `/etc/xdg/autostart/bluetooth-applet-unity.desktop` exist

Comment: Go into Terminal and type this: gksu nautilus /etc/xdg/autostart Then check and see if these two files are there: bluetooth-applet.desktop and bluetooth-applet-unity.desktop

Comment: Yes, the two files you said exists!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same issue when I did an update for Ubuntu 11.10. Today I got the problem solved.

Just had to install *blueman* like this:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Got it solved, bluetooth icon is now back in the unity top bar.